# Grafana / Azure Monitor dimension filtering without splitting

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-monitoring

I'm trying to display "Dependency duration" from Azure Monitor (Application Insights) in Grafana. I want to exclude "Azure Service Bus" from "dependency/type" dimension.

When I do this in Azure Monitor I get all dependencies as single value:
[image: Azure Monitor filtered dimensions]

When I try to apply same filter in Grafana, all dimensions get split:
[image: Grafana filtered dimensions]

How can I avoid splitting dimensions, or alternatively how can I combine them back into one? Relevant part of code below. I tried removing `"dimensionFilter": "*"` but it did not change anything.

```json
{
  "azureMonitor": {
    "dimensionFilter": "*",
    "dimensionFilters": [
      {
        "dimension": "dependency/type",
        "filter": "Azure Service Bus",
        "operator": "ne"
      }
    ],
    "dimensions": [
      {
        "text": "Dependency type",
        "value": "dependency/type"
      }
    ],
    "metricDefinition": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
    "metricName": "dependencies/duration",
    "metricNamespace": "microsoft.insights/components",
    "resourceGroup": "$resources_rg",
    "resourceName": "$app_insights"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No. I gave up and just use dependencies split by the dimension.